# What happened on DOM within Drupal file module ajax upload

Tags: ajax, drupal

Drupal has this ajax framework built-in. So, I can write a callback function with command like

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace(NULL, theme('status_messages'));
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

The output then gets processed by Drupal ajax framework in some way to ultimately manupulate the DOM. As the above function `_replace` which replace something in the DOM based on some wrapper ID.

This above code is from the `file` module shipped with Drupal. When upload a new file, the form will be updated to indicate a new file inserted in the form.

As the document said that the first argument could be `NULL` where it could be a `selector`. I am especially interested to know how this `file` module calculate out the wrapper ID so it can insert the DOM element as the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the drupal documentation page.

If the command is a response to a request from an #ajax form element then this value can be NULL.

In file_managed_file_process function you have the upload_button form element, which sends an ajax request to 'file/ajax/...' path.

The ajax_command_replace is used in the ajax callback in file_ajax_upload(). So the request is from the upload_button form element, in this case you can use NULL instead of a selector.

Comment: So how Drupal knows what to replace as the "selector"? The wrapper element of the trigger button element? Looks like the whole file field got replaced. So it's a whole child form?

Comment: It should replace the wrapper, specified in the $ajax_settings['wrapper']